# RichFaces fileUpload component hanging in IE7 - "Permission Denied"

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I've got a RichFaces (v 3.3.1) `fileUpload` component on my page that does not work in IE7 (haven't tested newer/older versions), but does fine in Firefox. If I try to upload a file in IE7, the "Uploading" bar appears but does not progress and the file doesn't get uploaded - in fact, the server never gets so much as a request.

I know that the RichFaces demo of the component works fine in IE7, so it's something I've done to break the fragile little bastard. Has anyone ever run into this problem? What could be causing it to not even send the HTTP request, but only in IE?

I'm going to try a couple things and then cave in and upgrade to the newest version of RichFaces. If you think you can save me some time, any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: After enabling script debugging in IE, I found that, when I click the "Upload" button on the fileUpload component, IE throws a "Permission Denied" error. I looked at the request in HttpFox in Firefox, and it showed that the TLD that it was uploading to was the same as that of the page. So I don't know what's causing it.

EDIT 2: HttpFox shows that the POST that sends the image to the server gives a result type of NS_BINDING_ABORTED. Note that's in the browser where this thing actually works. Could the "Permission Denied" error be a result of the page refresh request aborting the file upload POST?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Comment: I can't find any indication that it's trying to do https. I did find a separate and seemingly unrelated JS error on the page; I'm going to fix that and see if this problem automagically resolves itself.

Comment: It was just a question to exclude one and other. You're thus not using HTTPS (`rich:fileUpload` is known to have issues with that which behave smiliar as you're describing). Well, try to fix that other JS error first and report back.

Comment: Yeah it's not doing https. According to HttpFox, anyway.

Comment: Just looking at the URL scheme in browser address bar was also sufficient :)

Comment: Fixed the other problem. Still no dice on the fileUpload.

Comment: Well, try upgrading to RichFaces 3.3.3 (which is the latest 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Compare the html code
IE:

```
<head>
  ...
</head>
<form>
  ...
</form>
```

Firefox:

```
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</body>
```